# Hybris CMS Cockpit - add Javascript

Tags: content-management-system, sap-commerce-cloud

I am working with the Hybris CMS Cockpit (only as a user, not an admin) and I have built a page with the content slots.

However I am trying to insert some JavaScript into the page. I cannot see where I am mean't to add the JavaScript and I tried in-line `<script>` tags but they just get stripped out and turned to plain text.

Does anyone know if this is possible or will I have to ask an admin of the system to enable something?

Answer (score 4):

You can add javascript but you will have to have a developer make some overrides to the configuration files (local.properties) of the environments you want to add javascript in.

The settings are:

```
xss.filter.rule.script_fragments=
xss.filter.rule.lonely_script_tags=
xss.filter.rule.lonely_script_tags2=
xss.filter.rule.javascript=
```

By doing this, the system will no longer strip those tags  :)

Answer (score 2):

Typhoid Marty is correct, however to expand on his answer:

The Hybris Cross Site Scripting (XSS) filter is stripping out your script tags.

You will probably want to simply disable it for the extensions where your users will be editing the site, specifically the CMSCockpit, HMC and HAC:

```
hac.xss.filter.enabled=false
hmc.xss.filter.enabled=false
cmscockpit.xss.filter.enabled=false
```

You can find more configuration options for the XSS filter in the documentation here:
https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Web+Security+XSS+Filter

Answer (score 0):

Answers suggested by @Typhoid Marty and @kabadisha will fix the issue. Adding another workaround here. script can be added into content of component even if xss filter is configured as `xss.filter.enabled=true`.
This can be achieved by creating an impex for component and importing it via hac as a script with 'Enable code execution' check as true.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
document.body.style.backgroundColor="lavender";
<!-- document.write(Date()); -->
alert(document.getElementById("hai"));
}
</script>
```

In fact, Hybris cockpit use ZK framework, views are ".zul" files.

Comment: This looks irrelevant.